# Can't align image with div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't align image with a div.
I am using bootstrap, tried to create a row and add columns, but the image still slides lower than the edge of the div it is in.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/s4ek1389/pen/MbarmG?editors=1100)

```css
    .contacts {
      height:300px;
      background-color: #5E7BA7;
      text-align:center;
      padding-top:10px;
      color:white;
      font-size:18px;
    }
    
    #ava {
      border-radius:100%;
      
    }
```

```html
<div class="contacts" id="contacts">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <h2>Contact me</h1>
        <p>Get in touch with me and we will build something great.</p>
        <p>E-mail: s4ek1389@gmail.com</p>
        <a href="https://vk.com/s4ekotihin"class="btn btn-social-icon btn-vk"><i class="fa fa-vk"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100004760679976" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>  
      </div> <!-- col-xs-8-->
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img src="https://pp.vk.me/c636425/v636425401/55c29/w3KT6I3_x_0.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" id="ava"> 
      </div>
    </div> <!-- .row -->
  </div> <!-- .container-fluid -->
</div>  <!-- .contacts -->
```

I am trying to align my photo with the contacts block, so it is vertically centered.

How can  I fix this?

Comment: Sorry when you say you want to align the photo with the contacts block, do you mean you want the photo to be in the middle of the contacts block (vertically) or do you want it to be next to it?

Comment: it's not an alignment issue, you made .contacts 300px height, so the background doesn't extend to cover the full height of the content. https://codepen.io/LordNeo/pen/ggBjja?editors=1100

Comment: The contact block is 100% wide, so there is no way I can put the image next to it. I want it to be in the middle (vertically).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your height on .contacts. The image and padding is larger than 400px tall, so it overflows the contacts container. You can either let the height of contacts expand to the height of the image, or set the height of the image to a max-height of 400.

Comment: If you want to make it align vertically to the text, you can play around with the height of the image and it's containers padding untill it visually aligns verticly with the text, or you can get into to awesome world of https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/